# moving and reopening a closed question on programming career direction to more appropriate stack

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, reopen-closed

[gaming-development-vs-corporate-software-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664159/gaming-development-vs-corporate-software-development)

Revisited this old question when talking to someone about the difference in our enviroment from the gaming industry. Looks like a lot work went into the answer and would help those looking for this info. I can see that it was outside the scope of stackoverflow at the time.

Could we migrate this to something like "programmers" or "careers" and reopen so other folks might benefit from the work the answer provided on this issue? thanks

Comment: I don't think it would be on-topic on any SE site.

Comment: career and education advice is explicitly off-topic per [Programmers Help Center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/40980

Comment: The author of that post should be encouraged to post it on their blog.

Answer (score 3):

Questions cannot be migrated if they're older than 60 days, so no.

It also wouldn't be on topic on any of the site's you've mentioned, but as it can't be moved, that's a moot point.

Comment: Post is deleted, so even more moot.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's been deleted for 4 years, not exactly a recent development, but yes.  I didn't mention it in the answer simply because even if undeleted, it still couldn't be migrated.